# SwiftUI Alert setting presentation condition true in it's button action closure not showing the alert again

Tags: ios, swiftui, property-wrapper, swiftui-alert

So the thing I want to do is that I have an api call if it fails I show an alert with message, `OK` button and `Retry` Button.

Everything is working good but when I do retry it don't shows the alert again if it fails again and it's not showing alert again even if I am directly setting property which I am passing in `isPresented` as true by hard code in the closure by my self.

Here is the code.

```
.alert(isPresented: $viewModel.isErrorMessageVisible) {
        Alert(
          title: Text(StringsProvider.error), message: Text(viewModel.errorMessage),
          primaryButton: .default(Text(StringsProvider.ok), action: {
            // do nothing
          }),
          secondaryButton: .default(Text(StringsProvider.retry), action: {
            viewModel.isErrorMessageVisible = true
          }))
      }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You are trying to set the alert display binding to `true` in a button on the alert; as soon as the button action closure is executed, SwiftUI will set it back to `false`.

Comment: @Paulw11,
I agree with you that SwiftUI will set it false.
Saw that being done in debugger as well.
But if I am setting it true then shouldn't it be visible again?

In debug logs first it get's set `false` by SiwfUI and then `true` by the code in action closure.

I presented it this way to make it look readable and making debugging easy.
In actuality API gets called and then error should be shown.